# How to implement snap scrolling with custom scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I am using custom scroll bar for my html page (scrollbar plugin). when i used snap scroll css with scroll bar plugin its working fine but it destroyed the smoothness of the scroll bar. like when i scroll down then it stop for a moment and suddenly scroll down to next container.

here is the snap scroll css

```
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

I have also tried to use the Iscroll plugin but its not working for me.

Can anybody provide me any jquery/JavaScript solution or any custom scroll bar who have snap scrolling functionality?

Comment: Which scrollbar plugin are you using at the moment? Knowing that would make finding out what exactly is incompatible with scroll snap much easier :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
scroll-snap-type: y proximity
```

To create scroll snap use from this link :
[**practical css scroll spanpping**](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)